# parse form data in nodejs service

Tags: node.js, web-services, post

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({// to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true`enter code here`
}));

app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    console.log("inside log");
    console.log(req.body);
    var username = req.body.username;
    console.log(username);
});
```

As I have used urlencoded() whenever I post data in form data, I do not get data in req.body. i have attached image of postman

in case I send data in x-www-urlencoded then I get data

[image]

Please give me a solution to parse the data. I want to pass it in form data because I will be uploading an image too. So for image form data is must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use connect-multiparty npm module.

```
  global.app = module.exports = express();

var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

app.use(multipart());
```

> You not set content-type in postman because node server automatically set his content-type in header according to form-data file.

Comment: Yes. This works fine . But then Image doesnot get uploaded. I am uploading the image using blueimp-file-upload-expressjs. But it given error
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Comment: this is callback error . Just check u have not done callback twice in code .